# Не получается добавить ссылку в обозревателе решений Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

В обозревателе решений отсутствует пункт ссылки. При нажатии пкм по Зависимости нет пункта добавить ссылку. В чём причина?
Консольное приложение .NET 6

[image: Обозреватель решений]

[image: Меню пункта зависимости]

Comment: Ссылку на что?.

Comment: @tym32167 На System.Configuration

Comment: через нугет пробовали? https://www.nuget.org/packages/system.configuration.configurationmanager/

Comment: @tym32167 У меня вопрос больше не как установить, а где пункт ссылки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пункт меню Add Reference(не знаю как точно на русском) отсутствует для нового формата проектов csproj(net core и тд.). Для новых проектов нужно использовать nuget. Если же по какой то причине нужно использовать новый формат проекта для сборки под net framework, то тогда придется добавлять руками в csproj не обходимые ссылки. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31054070/3907965) есть пример как для framework 4.1.6 добавить ссылку на `System.Net.Http`